# Values for %ACTUAL_PATH% Alfresco filing path property

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I would like a user to drop a file into a smart folder, have an aspect attached to it, and have the file stored in a folder in a different location.

I have followed the smart folders tutorial, and read the "Smart Folder Template syntax" page (here https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/sf-ref-template-guidance.html). The examples I have found only ever show "%ACTUAL_PATH%" as the value for the path property.

What alternative values are possible for the path property of the filing rule? In the following example folder hierarchy, a user would drop a file into "General" and we would like the file stored in "Approved".

Example structure is:

Documents

-> Approved

-> Archived

-> Incoming

-> -> General (a smart folder)

I appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

1) XPAth

```
"/app:company_home/cm:Docments/cm:Approved"
```

2) You can drop to any other folder with rule on it, to specify more complicated logic to sort created files